# Error while adding two values from two netcdf files

Tags: arcpy, python, netcdf

I was writing the following code to add two values from two different netcdf files.

```
import netCDF4 as nc
m1 = nc.Dataset('m1.nc')
m2 = nc.Dataset('m2.nc')
a = m1.variables(['pr'][364][100][100] + m2.variables(['pr'][364][100][100]
print a
```

This code gave me an parsing error - invalid syntax. I thought that since we can extract the values in these cells, I should be able to add them and assign them to a variable. Clearly, I am wrong, can someone explain why and how this mechanism works?

Answer (score 1):

This does work but you have syntax errors, just remove the parentheses.

`a = m1.variables['pr'][364][100][100] + m2.variables['pr'][364][100][100]`